# DataContext initialization is giving errors

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

I am trying to create my own custom sign up. Which works

But when I add a stored procedure when I try to initialize dataContext it throws an error. Here is my code

```
namespace Login.Controllers.Work
{
    public class PostController : Controller
    {

        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        private readonly DataContext _context;

        private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public PostController(DataContext context, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,  SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager, IEmailSender emailSender,    ILogger<AccountsController> logger )
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _emailSender = emailSender;
            _logger = logger;
           _context = context;
        }
```

when I add , DataContext context and set it below as  _context = context;  I get error 500 in my ajax query

Error message is

HTTP500: SERVER ERROR - The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
(XHR)POST - https://localhost:44345/SignUp

What is wrong here ?

thanks

Comment: This isn't enough information for us to help. 500 errors always come with a lot more detail....

Comment: @DavidG its an ajax calll giving the error, how do I find specifics ?

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add the service registration in the startup.cs file

as

```
    services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
```

its ok now
thank you